# Data Sorting by one column

Tags: excel, sorting

I need to sort a column that has multiple criteria listed in it. I am trying to figure it out without having to reformat the whole spreadsheet (I did not make it). I need to sort the whole column by "ANAHEIM, CA-SALT LAKE CITY, UT" and then "Chill."

I have tried using a conditonal format for both and sorting it, then I have tried using a custom sort (which did it) but then when I tried to clear the sort it messed up my orginal formatting.

pic:

[image]

Comment: I would highly recommend a reformat here. This is not [tidy data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) and thus will give you a lot of problems to work with (such as the issue you have now). Would be much better with a location column and a few condition columns

Comment: Please **edit** your post to provide examples of your original data and desired output.

Comment: thanks, I cannot reformat as this isn't my data to begin with